# Running EMR in client mode, submitting applications from local

Tags: apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr

I'm learning more about the various modes that a spark cluster can be run with, and with respect to the `client` mode, how would I submit an application to an EMR cluster from local if the EMR cluster were running in client mode?

Is it possible to submit an application from a local spark instance to a Spark cluster running in EMR?